# Given a circle $(O, R)$ and a chord $AB=2a$. If $CA,CB$ tangents to it, then what is the area of $\triangle ABC$ equal to, with respect to a and R?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

Given a circle $(O, R)$ and a chord $AB=2a$. If $CA,CB$ tangents to it, then what is the area of $\triangle ABC$ equal to, with respect to a and R?

[image]

I tried solving this question as follows:

$AO=OB=R$

$\triangle ACO=\triangle BOC$

$CA=CB$

Since $OC\perp AB$ and $\triangle ACB$ iscosceles, we just need to find the hight of $\triangle ABO$, from point $O$. This is what gave me difficulties. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Join $OC$, mark some angles and using similarity or otherwise you can find all lengths.

Comment: $\angle OCA = \angle OAB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Then $OCA$ and $ OAM$ are similar, which leads to
$$[ABC]= \frac{AM^2}{OM^2} [OAB] =\frac{AM^2}{OM^2} \cdot \frac12  AB\cdot OM=\frac{AM^3}{OM}= \frac{a^3}{\sqrt{R^2 -{a^2}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$CAOB$ is a kite and a cyclic quadrilateral as well. Let the point at which $CO$ intersects $AB$ be $M$, the midpoint of $AB$.

Now,  $CM\cdot MO=AM\cdot BM$ because $CAOB$ is cyclic.  $AM=BM=a$ and $MO$ can be gotten from $\triangle OMA$ by applying the Pythagorean theorem. Find $CM$ and then proceed to use the formula for area.